# Embedding of classical Lie groups

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, big-picture

This is somehow very natural question so I'm sure that the answer should be well known: Whitney theorem states that each (say paracompact) $n$-dimensional manifold could be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$-but very often $2n$ is not necessesary, one could find smaller $m$ such that $n$ dimensional manifold could be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^{m}$. What are the minimal numbers $m$ such that the classical Lie groups such as $SU(n)$ or $SO(n)$ can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^m$?
What about the torus $\mathbb{T}^n$-could be always embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$?

Answer (score 0):

For the torus, the answer is positive, see:
[Embedding of n-Torus in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ via implicit function $T^n=f^{-1}(0)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307476/embedding-of-n-torus-in-mathbbrn1-via-implicit-function-tn-f-10)

For such compact groups if the dimension is not a power of two ( I'm pretty sure $\frac {n(n-1)} 2 \not= 2^k$ for all $n,k$) they can be embedded in $\mathbb R ^{2n-1}$ and that's the minimal n for $SO(3)$, but for $SU(2)$ is 4. Since $SU(n)$ is 2-connected it can be embedded in $\mathbb R ^{2n-2}$. Since any simplify connected lie group is also 2 connected the result can be improved to  $\mathbb R ^{2n-2}$ for  those if their dimension is bigger than 7.

See the Wikipedia article for the withney embedding theorem https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_embedding_theorem

Comment: Of course this is not a complete answer but I think being a lie group doesn't help to much  in this aspect

Comment: Being a Lie group helps a lot; it ensures that the tangent bundle is trivial, which removes a possible obstruction. So e.g. a connected Lie group of dimension $d$ immerses into $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ by the Hirsch-Smale theorem.

Comment: Do you know criteria to improve immersion to embedding?

Comment: $SU(2)$ and $SO(3)$ are isomorphic!