# Hyper $n-$ torus cohomology group?

Tags: algebraic-topology, terminology

I don't know if this interpretation is correct.

Is $S^{n_1} \times S^{n_2} \times \dots \times S^{n_k}$ some sort of hyper torus of dimension $1 + \sum_{k = 1} n_k$ (see [here for calculation)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161293/product-of-spheres-embeds-in-euclidean-space-of-1-dimension-higher)?

Let's just take an example, what exactly is object $S^2 \times S^3$ (need a name for this set)? By Kinneth's formula (thanks in the comments), I found that

$H^p(S^2 \times S^3) = \oplus ( H^i(S^2) \otimes H^j(S^3) ) $. For $p = 0$, we get $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R = \Bbb R^2$. For $p \geq 1$, (I only did it up to $p = 2$), I found that it stays $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Since there is no definition of what a «hyper torus of dimension $m$» is, it is impossible to answer your first question. Your computation of $H^p(S^2\times S^3)$ is not correct, by the way.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, how is it now?

Comment: Google for «Künneth formula»

Comment: If you are using $|S^2\times S^3|$ to denote the dimension of $S^2\times S^3$, that is also wrong: that manifold has dimension 5.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, oh never heard of that formula before. So I guess by that formula, I would have $H^p(S^2 \times S^3) = \oplus H^i(S^2) \otimes H^j(S^3) $. I found that for $p = 0$, we get $\Bbb R \otimes \Bbb R = \Bbb R^2$. For $p \geq 1$, (I only did it up to $p = 2$), I found that it stays $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: But thank you anyways, I'll brutally work out the calculations myself. You helped me enough.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}\otimes \mathbb{R}$ is actually just $\mathbb{R}$.